# Getting an invalid Object error while doing CTE operation in Stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I got an error invalid Object SubSkillIds  while executing this in a stored procedure? Can anybody let me know why is it so?

My error message looks like:-

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   SubSkillDelete, Line 47
>   Invalid object name 'SubSkillIds'.

Code:

```
WITH SubSkillIds (SubSkillId) AS
(
   -- Base case
   SELECT
        SubSkillId
   FROM dbo.SubSkill
   WHERE RegressionSubSkillId = @SubSkillId
   UNION ALL
   -- Recursive step
   SELECT
        S.SubSkillId
   FROM dbo.SubSkill S
   WHERE S.RegressionSubSkillId IN (
   SELECT
        SubSkillId
   FROM dbo.SubSkill
   WHERE RegressionSubSkillId = @SubSkillId)
)

SELECT  @SubSkillIdFound = SubSkillId
FROM SubSkill WHERE SubSkillId = @SubSkillId

DELETE FROM SubSkillActivity WHERE SubSkillId = @SubSkillId
DELETE FROM SubSkill WHERE RegressionSubSkillId
IN (SELECT * FROM SubSkillIds)
DELETE FROM SubSkill WHERE SubSkillId = @SubSkillId
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The CTE is only available for the next statement - your `SELECT......`

It is **no longer available** later on - that's why your second `DELETE` statement, which references that CTE, will fail.

If you need to keep the values of the CTE around for more than one single statement, you need to store those values into a temporary table / table variable.

Comment: +1. I think it would also be valid to say that a CTE is actually *a part* of the statement it precedes (in SQL Server, anyway).